# Copy linux directory into another one - delete contents

Tags: linux, file-transfer, recursive

**BIG EDIT**:

I currently have a directory with folders and files inside:

```
-css
--addons
---myaddon
----addon
-----firsfile.xml
-----secondfile.xml
----cfg
-----anotherfile.cfg
-----lastcfg.cfg
---mysecondaddon
----addon
-----thirdfile.xml
-----fourthfile.xml
----cfg
-----againfile.cfg
-----othercfg.cfg
```

I want to copy it in another directory:

```
-css_server_1
--cstrike
---cfg
```

Now I have a GUI allowing me to list my addons (/css/addons/) and I want to install one of the addons (mysecondaddon from /css/addons/mysecondaddon) on my first server (css_server_1/cstrike)

The final result must be:

```
-css_server_1
--cstrike
---addon
----firsfile.xml
----secondfile.xml
---cfg
----againfile.cfg
----othercfg.cfg
```

If I chose to add the other addon (myaddon from /css/addons/myaddon), the result will be:

```
-css_server_1
--cstrike
---addon
----firsfile.xml
----secondfile.xml
----thirdfile.xml
----fourthfile.xml
---cfg
----againfile.cfg
----othercfg.cfg
----againfile.cfg
----othercfg.cfg
```

Finally, I would want to remove one of the addons installed (mysecondaddon).

I am looking for a linux command allowing me to delete in the /css_server_1/cstrike directory all the files appearing in (/css/addons/mysecondaddon), so the result will be:

```
-css_server_1
--cstrike
---addon
----firsfile.xml
----secondfile.xml
---cfg
----againfile.cfg
----othercfg.cfg
```

I know I can use the rm -rf command to delete the /css_server_1/cstrike/addon folder, but this will delete all the addons...

I hope it was clearer this time :D

Comment: did you tried with -rf  options?

Comment: Why don't you `mv`?

Comment: mv will move the folder, I want to keep the source intact.

Comment: I'll rewrite it tomorrow

Comment: just edited my topic

Comment: Still confusing. For example you have two "againfile.cfg" files in the same directory (css_server_1/cstrike/cfg/).

Answer (score 1):

Your question is still confusing, but I think I know what you want to do. Take a look at the `rsync` command. For example:

```
rsync -av --delete css/addons/myaddon/ css_server_1/cstrike/
```

or something similar should do the trick for you. The important thing is the `--delete` option which will remove extraneous files from `css_server_1/cstrike/` that are not in `css/addons/myaddon/`.

Comment: Just edited the main topic, thx for your answer

Comment: it's getting interesting, I'm trying this tonight and will upvote helpful answers. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`rm -rf /path/to/directory/todelete`

or `mv /src /dest`